# Finding the Code words generated by a parity check matrix.

Tags: matrices, parity

I'm trying to find the code words generated by this matrix and then decode some given words and find the bit with the error for this parity check matrix(H):
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The encoded words are (011101), (110111), (111011), (111111).

The generator matrix (G) I got is:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The encoded words I got (in order for 000, 001, 010,...,110, 111) are 000000, 001101, 010011, 011110, 100101, 101001, 110100, 111001. I'm unsure whether they're correct or not though as these are from a sample paper w/o solutions so any corrections would be appreciated.